# bigquery - Input contained no data

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm testing bigquery platform with real traffic of my site (more than 80M of events by day).
I'm uploading gz files using java api, using insert jobs.
In some cases, i've receive this message: **Input contained no data**

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#job",
 "etag": "\"******************\"",
 "id": "*********",
 "selfLink": "********",
 "jobReference": {
    "projectId": "********",
    "jobId": "**************"
 },
 "configuration": {
    "load": {
     "schema": {
        "fields": [
         {
            "name": "tms",
            "type": "TIMESTAMP"
         },
         {
            "name": "page",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "user_agent",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "print_id",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "referer",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "gtms",
            "type": "TIMESTAMP"
         },
         {
            "name": "cookies",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "ip",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "site",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "call_params",
            "type": "STRING"
         },
         {
            "name": "domains",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "fields": [
             {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "STRING"
             },
             {
                "name": "ads",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                 {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "position",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "strategy",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "score",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "cpc",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "site",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "categ",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "cust",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "campaign",
                    "type": "STRING"
                 }
                ]
             }
            ]
         }
        ]
     },
     "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": "**********",
        "datasetId": "*******",
        "tableId": "********"
     },
     "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
     "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
     "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
    }
 },
 "status": {
    "state": "DONE",
    "errors": [
     {
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "Input contained no data"
     }
    ]
 },
 "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1416491042309",
    "startTime": "1416491061440",
    "endTime": "1416491076876",
    "load": {
     "inputFiles": "1",
     "inputFileBytes": "0",
     "outputRows": "0",
     "outputBytes": "0"
    }
 }
}
```

And then of this, all my jobs return the same response.
Can anybody tell me what is the reason of this behaviour?
Thanks!!!!

Comment: So sometimes the data gets ingested, but sometimes it doesn't? When it doesn't, is it consistent on retries, or does it fix itself? A job id would help the BigQuery team to debug, unless you include enough information to make the problem evident - then the community can help too.

Comment: From the statistics, it looks like your gzip file was empty. Did you really mean to load no data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your job succeeded: there is no "errorResult" field in the status.

First, I understand this mistake: the return of errors and warnings in the job api is, frankly, as clear as mud.

Here's the quick overview:

- `status.errorResult` is where job error is reported. If no errorResult is reported, the job succeeded.
- `status.errors` is where individual errors *and warnings* are reported.

Please reference the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs and search for `status.errorResult` and `status.errors`.

Most people don't hit this problem since a job only encountering a warning is pretty rare.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was very simple: the gz file.
Thanks!